# Prove there exists no vector that $\nabla\times A=\frac{\hat r}{r^2}$

Tags: vector-analysis

I need to prove that there exists no vector $A$ such that $\nabla\times A=\frac{\hat r}{r^2}$ ($r$ is the position vector, and $\hat r$ the unit position vector.).

Comment: Can you clarify the context? Isn't $A$ rather a *function* with vector values? - just to be able to apply $\nabla\times$. And is there any connection assumed between $r$ and $A$?

Comment: also, what's the meaning of dividing by a vector?

Comment: Actually $A$ is supposed to be the magnetic field $B$. $\frac{\hat{r}}{r^2}$ is the spatial part of a point charge electric field $E$. It is $r^2$, not $r$. I made a mistake.

Comment: @chak I didn't divide anything by a vector?

Comment: before editing you were dividing by $r$ which you say is the position vector...that was what i was pointing out

Comment: @chak You're right. I should've said the magnitude of the position vector.

Comment: @Simorq If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Comment: @Simorq If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly observe that the **necessary condition** is satisfied:

$$\bigtriangledown \cdot \left( \bigtriangledown \times A \right)=\bigtriangledown \cdot \frac{\hat r}{r^2}=0$$

infact:

$$\frac{\hat r}{r^2}=\left(\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac32},\frac{y}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac32},\frac{z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac32} \right)$$

thus

$$\bigtriangledown \cdot \frac{\hat r}{r^2}=0$$

infact

$$\frac{\partial{\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac32}}}{\partial x}=\frac{-2x^2+y^2+z^2}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac52}$$

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+derivative+x%2F(x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2)%5E(3%2F2)

> Even if the necessary condition is satisfied, if you consider a sphere centered in the origin, the flux of $\frac{\hat r}{r^2}$ is not equal to zero, thus **in general it is not possible** to find $A$ such that:
>
> $$\nabla\times A=\frac{\hat r}{r^2}$$

Comment: I don't understand. You mean it's impossible to prove wether such a vector exists or not?

Comment: It depends upon the domain you are working on. For a sphere centered at the origin A can't exixst. For others domain, as a sphere or radius 1 centered in (1,1,1) A exists.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What is the divergence of 
$$
\frac{\hat{r}}{r\cdot r}
$$
and what is the divergence of the curl of a vector field?

Comment: Very good hint.

Comment: The divergence of the curl of any vector field is zero, which means $\bigtriangledown .(\frac{\hat{r}}{r^2})=-2(\frac{x+y+z}{r^4})=0$

Comment: I don't think that computation is correct. Regardless, the divergence of right hand side is *not* identically 0

Comment: OK now I have the divergence equal to zero. But what does it mean?